# When column A is NA, I want to multiply the value in column B by the value immediately before column A

Tags: r, dataframe, na, dplyr

When column A is NA, I want to multiply the value in column B by the value immediately before column A.
I don't know how to accumulate when NAs are continuous. I want the result to look like column C below.

```
dat <- data.frame(A=c(1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1), B=c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2))

> dat
   A    B
1  1    1
2  1    2
3 NA    2
4  1    2
5 NA    2
6 NA    3
7 NA    4
8  1    2

#-------------------------------------------
# C is NAs
result <- 
    dat %>% 
    mutate(C = ifelse(is.na(A), lag(A)*B, A))

> result
   A B  C
1  1 1  1
2  1 2  1
3 NA 2  2
4  1 2  1
5 NA 2  2
6 NA 3 NA
7 NA 4 NA
8  1 2  1
#-------------------------------------------

> result
   A    B    C
1  1    1    1
2  1    2    1
3 NA    2    2
4  1    2    1
5 NA    2    2
6 NA    3    6
7 NA    4   24
8  1    2    1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the value before column A"? The value in column A in the row before? You give 2 arrays as result; what is your expected/intended output?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this using `for` loop :

```
dat$C <- NA

for(i in seq_len(nrow(dat))) {
   if (is.na(dat$A[i])) dat$C[i] <- dat$C[i-1] * dat$B[i]
   else dat$C[i] <- dat$A[i]
}

dat

#   A B  C
#1  1 1  1
#2  1 2  1
#3 NA 2  2
#4  1 2  1
#5 NA 2  2
#6 NA 3  6
#7 NA 4 24
#8  1 2  1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!
In fact, I don't want to use loops because the number of rows is very long. Is there a way not to use the "for" statement?

Comment: @richiee yeah, I tried to do without "for" loop here but was not successful. For loops are not that bad either you can try it and see how it performs.